# R Removing a list of days

Tags: r, date, xts

I work a lot on time series data, and I want to remove a number of days (specifically it's the daylight-savings days). So I have a list of days:

```
days <- c("2009-03-20", "2009-10-25", "2010-03-28", "2010-10-31", 
"2011-03-27", "2011-10-30", "2012-03-25", "2012-10-28", "2013-03-31")
```

I want to remove all the observations on these days. Now, here is my data:

```
dato <-seq(as.POSIXlt("2009-01-01"), as.POSIXlt("2013-10-08"), "hour")
x<-runif(41784)*100
y<-runif(41784)*100
df<-cbind(dato, x, y)
```

I can pick out the days with xts, but I cant figure out how to remove these days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me your problem is that you have dates in the format yyyy-mm-dd but your `dato` column is in hours. If you reformat that `dato` column or add a column with formatted dates, you should be able to use `%in%` negated to remove those days. If you run the code below and check `mydf2` you will see that it no longer contains any rows for the dates in `drop.days`. You don't need `xts` for this specifically (though it contains nice subsetting functions).

```
mydf <- data.frame(hours = seq(as.POSIXlt("2013-10-01"),
                       as.POSIXlt("2013-10-08"), "hour"),
                   val1 = runif(169)*100,
                   val2 = runif(169)*100)

mydf$date <- format(mydf$hours, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

unique(mydf$date)

drop.days <- c('2013-10-03','2013-10-04')

mydf2 <- mydf[!(mydf$date %in% drop.days), ]
```

Comment: Nice clear example/explanation. I find working with dates tricky, because everyone has a different take on them, xts, zoo, chrome, RcppBDT and more? So as a new R-user it is good to see this was pretty simple and straighforward to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
days <- c("2009-03-20", "2009-10-25", "2010-03-28", "2010-10-31", 
          "2011-03-27", "2011-10-30", "2012-03-25", "2012-10-28", "2013-03-31")
days <- as.Date(days) # convert to Date
dato <-seq(as.POSIXlt("2009-01-01"), as.POSIXlt("2013-10-08"), "hour")
x <- runif(41784)*100
y <- runif(41784)*100
df <- data.frame(dato, x, y) # convert to data.frame not matrix
df_1 <- subset(df, !as.Date(dato) %in% days) # remove days
```